# Is it possible to make changes on Google Drive side by command line

Tags: macos, google-drive-api

Is it possible to access Google Drive by command line and do some changes to video/mp3 files?

Like for example I do to my local files `for f in *.mp4; do echo $(ruby -e 'puts "name"') >> "$f"; done`

Is it possible to connect to Google Drive and make all changes there  without Downloading/Sync?

Right now I download files first to my PC, make changes and then upload files back to Google Drive.

Comment: no it isn't possible in the way you've expressed it. You are of course free to write your own app to do anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you would need to write such command-line app using the google drive api. there is no official app to do that.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I just look at  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update 
& It looks like I am able to change only metadata, right? If I can change/add some data to mp3.file - what kind of API should I use? or any link? please. 
Thank you.

Comment: sorry but thats a separate question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824769/how-to-find-and-change-add-content-to-media-files-on-google-drive-by-ruby
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[**gdrive**](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) is a command-line utility to access a remote google drive account. Follow this example for a Linux machine to set this up:

1. At first download the execution file of gdrive [here](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/releases).
2. Decompress it and get the executable file `gdrive`. Now change the permissions of the file by executing the command
   `chmod +x gdrive`.
3. Run `./gdrive about` and you will get a URL asking you to enter for a verification code.
   As instructed in the prompt copy the link and go to the URL on your **browser**, then log into your Google Drive account and grant permission. You will get some verification code at last. Copy it.
4. Go back to your previous terminal and paste the verification code you just copied. Then verify
   your information there. Now you successfully link your machine to your Google Drive
   account.

Now once done with the above process you can navigate the files on your drive using the commands mentioned below.

```
./gdrive list # List all files' information in your account
./gdrive list -q "name contains 'University'" # serch files by name
./gdrive download fileID # Download some file. You can find the fileID from the 'gdrive list' result.
./gdrive upload filename  #  Upload a local file to your google drive account.
./gdrive mkdir # Create new folder
```

Hopefully, it helps.