# Can I run Ruby code on Google server to change content of media files?

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

Can I run this code on Google server?

```
require "rubygems"
require "google/api_client"
require "google_drive"
require 'launchy'

# Creates a session.
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)

# Gets list of remote files.
for file in session.files
  file.update_from_string(file.download_to_string() + " name")
end
```

Or I have to use Google Apps Script or Google App Engine?

Comment: Look at the api. Code it. Post code and what doesnt work.

Comment: @Zig Mandel Sorry for that, I made some progress.

Comment: You want to update the content or the name of the file? Seems like you are asking way too fast. Spend a couple hours looking at the api and googling first.

Comment: Sorry but question doesnt make sense and still havent answered my question above

Comment: @Zig Mandel 
Sorry, I want to update the content of the files. 
The code does work - but it's slow and it's downloading files - that's why I want to run it on the server if I can.

Comment: Not possible. Clarify that on the title and question.

Comment: Done, sorry, just to clarify - it can't be done even by Google Apps Script or Google App Engine? Sorry for so many questions. Thank you.

Comment: sorry you really need to read the s.o, guidelines on how to ask a good question. after all this chat you still havent made clear in the question that you want some sort of "append" feature instead of rebuilding the whole contents again. This also can be answered by reading the google drive api directly (skip the ruby wrapper)

Comment: also, never ever publish an access token. Your google drive has been hackable for the first hour you posted your question. Code also needs an oauth flow.